# on submit two things happen

Tags: php, html, curl, paypal, e-commerce

My form action sends hidden inputs to PayPal for checkout. I also need it to send me an email before it goes to paypal.

But since the action of my form calls paypal I cant trigger the other function. I was thinking I could just have the action=self and do what I need on my page and then send the nessesery post variables to paypal. I am taking a shot at it below:

```
<?
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
//get post data for me clean up and save then send

if(!mail(data, myemail, headers)){
//send data to paypal. 
curl(https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr);
}

}else{
?>
<form action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post">
<!-- DATA FOR ME-->

<p>Child's Name: <? echo $child_name; ?></p>
    <input type="hidden" name="child_name" value="<? echo $child_name; ?>">

<p>Birth Date: <? echo $birth_date; ?></p>
    <input type="hidden" name="birth_date" value="<? echo $birth_date; ?>">

<p>Parent/Guardian Name: <? echo $name; ?></p>
    <input type="hidden" name="name" value="<? echo $name; ?>">

<p>Email Address: <? echo $email; ?></p>
    <input type="hidden" name="email" value="<? echo $email; ?>">

<p>Home Phone: <? echo $phone; ?></p>
    <input type="hidden" name="phone" value="<? echo $phone; ?>">



<!-- DATA FOR PAYPAL-->
<input type="hidden" name="business" value="you@youremail.com">
<input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="Item Name">
<input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="USD">
<input type="hidden" name="amount" value="<?php echo $total; ?>">
<input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_s-xclick">
<input type="hidden" name="hosted_button_id" value="XXXXXXXXXX">
<input type="image" src="https://www.paypal.com/en_US/i/btn/btn_paynowCC_LG.gif" border="0" name="submit" alt="PayPal - The safer, easier way to pay online!">
</form>
```

Should I use curl to resend the data to PayPal once the mail() function on my page was successful? Not sure how that will work?

Comment: Instead of the action you can use an onClick() on the Submit button which calls a method to send the email and then calls form.submit;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May be like this

```
<?
$url = "";

if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
//get post data for me clean up and save then send

    if(!mail(data, myemail, headers)){
        $url = "https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr";
    }

}else{
?>
<form action="<? echo $url; ?>" method="post">

<!-- Same form as in the original post -->

</form>

<?
if ($url != "") {
?>
<script language="javascript">
document.forms[0].submit();
</script>
<?
}
?>
```

Comment: Thanks I used the method above and it is serving my purposes. The data is not getting to Paypal but that has to do with the names of the inputs I think. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

> - [Introducing IPN](https://cms.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/?cmd=_render-content&content_ID=developer/e_howto_admin_IPNIntro)
> - [HTML Variables for Website Payments Standard](https://cms.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/?cmd=_render-content&content_ID=developer/e_howto_html_Appx_websitestandard_htmlvariables)

```
<input type='hidden' name='notify_url' value='http://yoursite.com/post.php?action=ipn' />
<input type='hidden' name='cancel_return' value='http://yoursite.com/post.php?action=cancel' />
<input type='hidden' name='return' value='http://yoursite.com/post.php?action=return' />
```

better to use a class like

> - http://www.micahcarrick.com/php-paypal-ipn-integration-class.html

Answer (score 0):

Why not just with javascript? An onsubmit routine can POST to a CGI script that sends you an email, then return a true value so that the normal submit follows through to PayPal.

---

Come to think of it, you'd need to use AJAX methodology so your browser stays on the same page.

Comment: Yes, but apart from the onsubmit using an ajax request rather than a post that's the way to go. :)